# Transforming if in single LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling to transform this piece of code in a single LINQ expression.

```
var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (x == null)
{
    x = values
        .Where(v => v.Columns.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code))
        .Select(v => v.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Basically I have a list of objects. Each objects contains a list of `Column` objects and a `Value`.

I want to filter the object that contains a specific `Column` object (based on `Code` and `Value`), but if this combination does not exist, I want to fall back to the entity that contains a list of `Column` objects all having `Code` equals to `string.Empty` (a wild card).

I have tried different approches like the following but without success:

```
var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value)
        ? v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value)
        : v => v.Columns.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just a general tip, if you want to do this in one linq statement, I would write it in its own mehtod with a good name. Just for the future and readability

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `Concat` both alternatives:

```
var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .Concat(values // second alternative if 1st returns empty cursor
       .Where(v => v.Columns.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code))
       .Select(v => v.Value))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit**: You can simplify the query (see CSharpie's comment) by extracting `.Select(v => v.Value)` into

```
var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))
    .Concat(values // second alternative if 1st returns empty cursor
       .Where(v => v.Columns.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code)))
    .Select(v => v.Value) 
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This still isn't a "single LINQ expression", it's two nested ones, strictly speaking. Nothing wrong with that mind you but if that's permitted then wouldn't a simple use of `??` (null coalescing operator) be clearer still? (I.e.,  `x = (firstQuery).FirstOrDefault() ?? (secondQuery);`

Comment: Nicre. But what i don't like is that it doesn't work well if you want to take 2 or more

Comment: @TypeIA: Yes it's a nested Linq, but since the very first line -  `.Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))` nests a query - `.Any(...)` I let myself doing in this way. Conditional operator `??` will do unless the `v.Value` is a *value type* - `stuct`; that's why I've prefered `Concat`.

Comment: `.Select(v => v.Value)` can be moved to the end of the Query so you wont need it twice.

Comment: @CSharpie: Thank you! You are quite right with `Select(v => v.Value)`; but I think my goal is to show the idea: `Contain` all alternatives and only then `.FirstOrDefault()` to take the first value from the first non-empty alternative. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty(fallback)`:

```
var fallBackValue =  values
    .Where(v =>  v.Columns.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(fallBackValue)
    .First(); // FirstOrDefault not nessesary anymore;
```

This has the advantage that you can even select multiple without breaking the logic, so the fallback value would still be returned if `Take(3)`(for example) would not return any items.

It is also efficient since the fallback value will be calculated independently of the main query and could be returned from a property, so that it needs to be initialized only once.

Another (similar option) is the null coalescing operator(if `Value` is a reference type):

```
var x = values
    .Where(v => v.Columns.Any(c => c.Code == code && c.Value == value))
    .Select(v => v.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? fallBackValue;
```

But i'd prefer the first because it can be chained and also modified easily(i.e. `Take(x)`).

Comment: This iterates `values` to determine the fallback even if its not needed.

Comment: @CSharpie: but only once for the whole query. Maybe that could even be stored in a field when it doesn't change (often). At least it is not related to the object itself so you can decouple it from the query.

Comment: @CSharpie: but just saw the "single LINQ expression" requirement